# Can not add highest bid to page in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm making a Django auction website. The problem is that I have no idea how to add highest bid to index page so that it updates every time user places a bid on another page.

views.py:

```
def index(request):
    index = listing.objects.filter(end_auction=False)
    number=len(index)
    return render(request, "auctions/index.html", {"list":index, "number":number})
```

models.py:

```
class listing(models.Model):
    Title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Description = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, null=True, decimal_places=2)
    image=models.ImageField( blank = True,
                          null = True,
                          upload_to ='')
    category = models.ForeignKey(category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="categories")
    end_auction=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.Title}"

class bid(models.Model):
    listing = models.ForeignKey(listing, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bid = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, null=True, decimal_places=2)
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.bid}, {self.listing}, {self.user}"
```

Keep in mind that I didn't include the whole code which is rather long. If you want me to add something just let me know! Answer would be greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can [**`.annotate(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) with:

```
from django.db.models import Max

def index(request):
    index = listing.objects.filter(maxbid=Max('bid__bid')).filter(end_auction=False)
    number=len(index)
    return render(request, "auctions/index.html", {"list":index, "number":number})
```

The `listing` objects that arise from this `QuerySet` will have an extra attribute `.maxbid` that is the largest of the bids.

In the template you thus can render this with:

```
{% for item in list %}
    {{ item.Title }}: {{ item.maxbid }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This is considering the option that I have maxbid ForeignKey in my listing model right?

Comment: @Leon_idas: no, it will make `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, so it will query the relation in "reverse". So *without* a `ForeignKey` named `maxbid`.